# Allowing localhost only in ASP.NET using <security>

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config

I am trying to allow access to my ASP.NET application only from `localhost`. An extract of my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
      <clear/>
      <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" />
    </ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

However, navigating to `localhost:52247` yields an `HTTP Error 403.503 - Forbidden` error. How do I specify that I would like to allow access from `localhost`? I have tried specifying the port but that didn't work. I have looked at lots of posts around the WWW without much success.

I have also tried `<add domainName='localhost' />`, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Had to add `allowed='true'`, like this:

```
<add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
```